# Why do I have to include `BufRead` and `Write` in the below `use` declaration?

Tags: rust

Why do I have to include `BufRead` and `Write` in the below `use` declaration?

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead, Write};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        io::stdout().write(line.unwrap().as_bytes())?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

From the documentation I understand that `use` basically gives you a shorthand way to refer to names, but here `Write` and especially `BufRead` are not used in the code directly. `write` looks like a method on whatever `io::stdout()` returns and `BufRead` is not mentioned in the code at all.

What are the rules on how to figure out what `use` declarations are necessary?